# Multiplying a matrix by another matrix to a power

Tags: linear-algebra

Take $M(A^{3})M^{-1}$

I expect this to be $MA^{3}M^{-1}$ by the associativity of matrix
multiplication.

But the video below says that it is $MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}$

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUuxdk_V7To&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare

Why is this?

Comment: Damn. Wow okay thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Cancel out the $M^{-1}M$ occurrences in the video’s formula to see what you get.

Both you and the video are correct.

This is a common formula for “conjugation.”

$$\left(MAM^{-1}\right)\left(MBM^{-1}\right)=M(AB)M^{-1}$$

and thus by induction:

$$\left(MAM^{-1}\right)^n=MA^nM^{-1}$$

Given an invertible $M$, the function $f(A)=MAM^{-1}$ is called conjugation by $M,$ and has the peoperties:

1. $f(I)=I,$
2. $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$
3. $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$
4. $f(A)=f(B)$ only if $A=B$
5. Given $B$ there is $A$ with $f(A)=B.$

Altogether, this makes $f$ What we call an “automorphism” on the ring of $n\times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 1):

notice that:
$$\left(MAM^{-1}\right)^3=MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}$$
$$=MAIAIAM^{-1}=MAAAM^{-1}=MA^3M^{-1}$$